# Lexical density

Tags: english, lexicon

I'm trying to work out the lexical density of a spoken text. My problem is with contractions that include a primary auxiliary verb as a main lexical verb.

E.g. She's intelligent.

From what I understand 'she' would count as a function word. The 'is' would count as a lexical word. Although it's a primary auxiliary verb in the sentence, it is acting as the main lexical verb.

'Intelligent' would also be a lexical word.

So how would I calculate the lexical density? Are there 2 lexical words and 1 function word? - 3 tokens in total = 0.66. Or are there 1.5 lexical words and .5 function words? - 2 tokens in total = 0.75

Comment: Since contractions can be written as two words, I'd recommend counting them as two regardless of whether they're contracted or not.